# Opening Electron app in 100% Fullscreen mode

Tags: electron

I'm creating an electron app and want to open it in fullscreen. `win.maximize()` doesn't work for me: it doesn't overlap the windows taskbar

How to solve this?

What's I do:

```
win.setMenuBarVisibility(false)
win.maximize()
win.show()
win.setAlwaysOnTop(true, 'normal')
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to display the window in fullscreen mode all the time (i.e. once it has been created), you can use the `fullscreen` option on the `BrowserWindow` constructor, see [its docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window#new-browserwindowoptions).

Thus, you could use something like

```js
// In the main process at window creation
let win = new BrowserWindow ({
    // your other options, like size etc.
    fullscreen: true
});
```

Note that the `width` and `height` options will only take effect if the window is un-fullscreened by the user and don't have any implications when the window is in fullscreen mode.